# Regex for one word, no white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsley

Is there a simple regex that only matches one word with no white space?

I am using parsley to validate Cognito username.  Cognito allows *any* character for username, as long as there is no whitespace, and returns an error if you enter a whitespace that says your username must match the pattern [\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+

According to regex sandbox sites, this pattern matches any number of words separated by whitespace.  To complicate matters, parsley pattern matching marks anything I type as invalid with this regex

data-parsley-pattern="[\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+"

Surely there is a simpler regex for one word with no whitespace?  Preferably one that will not blow up parsley?

Comment: Try `^\S+$`.....

Comment: Have you tried your pattern? Because it doesn't make much sense. https://regex101.com/r/yqfq0p/1

Comment: Yeah, that pattern matches anything except white space.  But when you use it in a regex tester, it will match both words on either side of the white space instead of rejecting the string.  Parsley doesn't seem to understand the pattern, though.  Yours works like a charm, thanks!